# Badge Holders Page Broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, design

As seen below on both the beta theme and graduated sites themes, on the tag editor (and some other badges) badge holders page the columns overlap.

Appears to be on all sites (have checked beta theme, skeptics, MSO, SO, Apple and English).

[image: Beta theme tag editor badge]

### After being marked as not reproducible after the help centre changes:

Sorry, but this isn't fixed and has actually been made **much worse** by the new changes:

[image: New worsened problem]

As you can see its now not only badges getting cut off but the end of peoples usernames and reputation scores too in addition to affecting pretty much everyone rather than just users with longer names.

Comment: OK, Rory indeed was 6 days faster than me. Thus, it is `Tag Editor` and `Electorate` and possible other badges. Is there a plan to fix this? +1 for this!

Comment: This happens for quite a few other badges, e.g.: [Strunk & White](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/12?page=46)

Comment: +1, since this obviously hasn't been fixed yet. ;-)

Comment: *this hasn't been fixed by new changes*

Comment: My bad, sorry... I flagged this without checking deep enough. Voting to reopen and slapping myself with a fish. @Anna - not your fault! :)

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed by badges changes of some months ago:

[image]

Comment: Also reported, and not fixed, on the [Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29710/181886). I understand that the software base is different and a fix here isn't applied there. The bug is identical.