# Columns in badge lists seem too narrow

Tags: bug, badges, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge Holders Page Broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129269/badge-holders-page-broken)

When looking at a badges site (here: [electorate@tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/44/electorate)), I noticed that either the user names are too long or the columns are too small. This results in the listed badges being cut off at the right. It happens at other SE sites and for other badges, too. There seems to be some spare space at the right of the table, maybe some of that could be used for increasing the column width? (Site seen with Firefox 3.6.28 as well as with 12.0, 13.0, all @ Win XP.)

[image: badges]

Comment: I've noticed this issue on several sites (both with IE8 on Win7 and Firefox (?) on WinXP)

Comment: Repro Chrome Canary

Comment: Repro Chrome Dev

Comment: @Rory: OK, your report was indeed 6 days earlier than mine. Thus, it is `Tag Editor` and `Electorate` and possible other badges. Is there a plan to fix this?