# Users with high number of badges break layout

Tags: bug, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jon Skeet's broken the C# tag stats page formatting on SO!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63867/jon-skeets-broken-the-c-tag-stats-page-formatting-on-so)

I was checking the [Java top users page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers) earlier and noticed that Jon Skeet's number of badges is too large to be displayed in the layout:

> [image]

But then I wondered, is it a bug or is it just so because one can't put Jon Skeet in a box?

Bug or not bug? That is the question.

Comment: Jon Skeet is not a bug, its the only human on stackoverflow.

Comment: +1 for "Skeet in a box" ;)

Comment: They're badges, not medals... Medals are lame...

Comment: Now why did I read that as "Jon Skeet has too many badgers!"?

Comment: @animuson Edited.

Comment: Related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129269/badge-holders-page-broken) which is similar on the badge holders page (3 column overlap)

Comment: What? Someone mention badgers? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIyixC9NsLI

Comment: Badgers are always one too many, even when there is just a badger, and especially when they are in your house. `;)`

Comment: related question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136988/layout-issue-on-tag-top-users-page

Comment: Hehee [this has been fixed once](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63867/jon-skeets-broken-the-c-tag-stats-page-formatting-on-so)

Comment: Hmmmm solution is to share badges ... with me :). But keep your badgers ! ... Glad to help debate ;)

Answer (score 6):

This is an ongoing struggle. The SE network tries to provide the users with a flawless Q&A engine.  And the users are working hard to find the flaws in the system.

Comment: "...So far, the Universe is winning." ([Rich Cook](http://quotes4all.net/rich%20cook.html))

Answer (score 3):

I would not call it a bug. The SE network is in a growing stage. Whoever has designed that page might not have thought that someone might reach this number of badges. But as these kind of reports are submitted to SE, I am sure there are developers who keep such things in mind. And while performing the page layout update your bug report will be kept in mind by the SE developers.

Comment: It's still a bug, unless the page was designed to look like that when a user has that many badges.

Comment: @Juhana You can never predict a 100% of the situation. In this way you can call it bug