# Jon Skeet is getting out of line

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, top-users

Jon Skeet's achievements seem to be messing with the layout in the top users page of some tags. For example, in the Android tag:

[image]

His badges and reputation push the line forward enough for it to hit another user's profile (in this case mine, but not the point here).

I understand that Jon is probably the only user who can cause this effect right now, but could we please have the layout widened a little bit?

Comment: You know you're Jon Skeet when...there isn't enough room on the page to list the *number* of badges you have.

Comment: This is a duplicate. Trying to find it now.

Comment: @DannyBeckett [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142380/187954) one?

Comment: @DannyBeckett: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63867/jon-skeets-broken-the-c-tag-stats-page-formatting-on-so), but it's `status-completed`

Comment: @Ullallulloo Yup, just found it. You're right though, flagged that question as not completed.

Comment: You both do realize that the 'completed' status there is meant as a joke, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Obviously Sam's answer is a joke. But it was Oded that added the [status-complete] tag.

Comment: So jon skeet has used the "answering questions to a high quality" exploit to hack the stack exchange server, ruining its formatting. Serious deeds indeed

Comment: To be fair, I think it's quite a while since I've added an extra digit in any aspect. Although the "2" at the start of the gold badges is a bit wider than the "1" which was there for a long time.

Comment: Fixed - added some space there. With you in rev 2013.7.18.860

Comment: @Oded - We need to retag this question with [jon-skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jon-skeet) :P

Comment: Is this question an annual phenomenon? It seems to get asked every year?

Comment: The title was a play on words, right?  I get it.

Comment: We could equally solve this by taking away some of his badges.

Answer (score 28):

Need to add the code that prints "3.3k" rather than "3312" in there.

Comment: Also don't forget the logic for millions as well as thousands.  It's only a matter of time after all.

Comment: @Servy isn't there already? The day is nigh.

Comment: He's already past 600,000... The day _is_ nigh.

Answer (score 20):

I'm honestly in favor of just changing Skeet's badge counts and reputation to ∞ (a lemniscate, denoting infinity) on pages besides his own profile page.  It should punt this problem off a few years.

Note this isn't just Skeet-worship - scales to any user with > 1k bronze badges. And from the detailed page anyone curious enough can find out the true badge count.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the word lemniscate (like me): ∞

Comment: @DannyBeckett I may have been too lazy to look up UTF-8 for it or whatever.

Comment: The weather isn't cold enough for lemniskating yet.