# Tag count of long tags breaking the layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

I noticed this issue just now when I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111082/chrome-extension-appending-div-to-body-not-working-with-facebook-like-button) on SO.

[image: This is the problem].

The tag count 379 is falling outside the body of page. Its readable now but as the count increases it will not be.

Maybe show the count for very-very-long-tags on hover? Or wrap and show such tags in multiple lines?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129269/badge-holders-page-broken)

Answer (score 1):

Tag count display has since been made to wrap. Marking as completed.