# Is there enough space in the user card for users who have a very large number of badges?

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges, user-interface, user-card

As you can see from [any of his answers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/237689/540162), Jon Skeet has successfully broken Stack Overflow's badge flair UI.

[image: Jon Skeet's badges get cut off]

---

#### Proposed solution:

When badges reach an incredibly high number (say in the thousands), abbreviate them as `k`s as opposed to thousands?

**Example:** Instead of displaying his current rep/badges line reading

> **505k** •153 •2493 •3879

the new version would read

> **505k** •153 •2.5k •3.9k

---

## Update:

It appears this behavior is only experienced when zooming the browser at odd intervals. After re-checking my screenshot, and the production site, the badges will only cut off at certain levels of zoom.

---

**Related:**

[Jon Skeet's broken the C# tag stats page formatting on SO!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63867/jon-skeets-broken-the-c-tag-stats-page-formatting-on-so)
[Badge count getting truncated in questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122735/badge-count-getting-truncated-in-questions-list)
[Badge Holders Page Broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129269/badge-holders-page-broken)

Comment: Good suggestion but personally I think it is "too localized" :)

Comment: Hmm, I seem to recall this is a dupe. Can't find it though.

Comment: @Bart If it is, I'll gladly vote this for closure as a dupe, but I did check beforehand to try to avoid that.

Comment: Similar http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63867 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122735

Comment: @Nightfirecat Don't worry. It's just this Skeet fellow causing problems all the time.

Comment: Yep, the second one is indeed the one I meant. Not a precise dupe, but close enough?

Comment: Close enough for me to link them anyway. Not sure if all the cases that they occur are the same, though.

Comment: The simple solution would be to suspend that Skeet fellow, then his reputation would be locked at 1 and there would be enough space for his badges.

Comment: @Bart that other question is just a bug report; this one here is feature request suggesting way to fix it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah, guess so. Although the solution is somewhat implied given how most other values on the site work.

Comment: For what it's worth, even adding "k" won't help. At some point (year, maybe two) The Skeet with reach 10,100 bronze badges and 10.1K will also break the UI.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well, at that point, we can give up on keeping track of the hundreds and round it down to 10k flat until he's closer to 11k.

Comment: @Nightfirecat fair enough, you got my vote! :)

Comment: They should rollover to 0 once they hit the ridiculously high numbers that break the UI.

Comment: Maybe we should have a "Jon Skeet rule" for displaying badges in the flair and just write "way more than you" instead of listing each class of badges and the count separately (although probably not enough room for that, so it might need to be a shorter phrase).

Comment: I'll start thinking that Jon Skeet is just a control mechanism. [He](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_(The_Matrix)) seems like he can accomplish superhuman things, but his real purpose is to point out the quirks and bugs in the framework.

Comment: That’s the penalty for missing the Analytical badge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Badge count getting truncated in questions list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122735/badge-count-getting-truncated-in-questions-list)

Comment: Didn't you just abbreviate 4 numbers to just another 4 symbols again?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov StackOverflow doesn't use a monospaced font, so a `.` takes up less width than any number. Admittedly, it could be truncated further to the nearest thousand, avoiding the `.#` entirely.

Comment: I just looked and it seems like this issue has been resolved. (At least for IE9 on Windows 7.)

Answer (score 12):

Let me take a moment to introduce you to a fella who has largely gone unnoticed in Stack Exchange pop culture, [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov). This Stack Overflow user doesn't have a Darin Dimitrov facts page, nor is he treated like the minor celebrity that Jon Skeet has become, yet this person is Stack Overflow's #2 user, sporting a reputation of 378,615 at the time of this writing.

[image: Darin Dimitrov SO Flair]

Darin Dimitrov has a whopping 27 gold badges, 618 silver badges, and 853 bronze badges, which is more than many of us have on the entire network! As you can see from one of his posts, he's nowhere near breaking the UI:

---

[image: Example of one of Darin Dimitrov's posts]

---

Thus, the feature that we're discussing here only visually affects a single user's profile on not just Stack Overflow but the entire Stack Exchange network.

Jon Skeet has answered a total of 23,486 questions on Stack Overflow, out of over 4,000,000 questions on the site, which represents only 0.58% of the total posts on the site. In short, not many people are exposed to what is arguably a borderline case on the network.

I suspect that it wouldn't be hard to update the flair to just round the numbers to "3k" or something like that, and I'm sure that Stack Exchange developers could put a fix in very quickly for this. However, I don't believe it's a huge priority that should be tackled over features that directly improve the Q&A.

Comment: according to your calculations, the problem is visible at "23,486 questions" (would be interesting to also count number of views for these questions). That hardly sounds like "not many people are exposed" to it. Though your logic that problematic profile is unique is quite compelling; taking this into account one solution to problem that springs to mind would be to just display a unicorn instead of Skeet's flair

Comment: @gnat - I did take the lazier route in those calculations, which assumes that all questions get the same number of views. From my own observations, I don't come across a lot of the questions Jon Skeet answers, so I wouldn't be surprised if the count based on total views is still low. I suspect the numbers might be slightly higher if there are people following him around the site, which wouldn't surprise me one bit, actually, since there have been feature requests asking for the ability to follow him.

Comment: +1 for highlighting Darin (or Marc, for that matter, who was #2 for a long time) but I don't agree with the reasoning on why the bug shouldn't be fixed with priority. SO's interface is famous for its perfectionism as much as its minimalism, and this is a glitch that should be fixed, no matter how few users it affects. IMO. Where Jon Skeet goes, eventually the rest will go, too

Comment: Hi @Pekka, I'm not saying it shouldn't be fixed. I'm merely pointing out criteria that can be used to prioritize this over other bugs, even other bugs that affect the UI. If this is deemed to be a higher priority over, let's say, Programmers SE hyperlinks, or the lack of consistency in underlining hyperlinks on beta sites, or other examples of UI bugs, then this should of course be prioritized as such. ;)

Comment: Darin has since broken 4 digits for silver and bronze, but the user card doesn't overflow. I wonder if it's because he still has only a two-digit gold count.

Comment: Darin hasn't broken the user card yet but [#3  (BalusC)](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) has

Comment: Aaaand Darin has broken the user card.

Comment: @Motti - Wow. It took almost 3 years, and still only affects the top 3 users. :)

Comment: @jmort253 actually 5 in stackoverflow alone. (see my edit that it happens in other sites too). Also since the _users reached_ count of these 5 people is more than the population of the united states I think ignoring it doesn't make sense (the fact that we saw the problem coming doesn't make it less of a problem).

Answer (score 6):

This now effects <strike>four users (although still not Darin Dimitrov)</strike> so I don't really think it's quite as localized as [@jmort253 thinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156671/3848).

**Edit:** Actually I've stopped counting, Darin is also breaking the cards and there are users in [other stack exchanges too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg).

A compounding facor is that these few users have very high visibility due to the high volume and quality of their contributions. So more people are exposed to the bug than one might think just based on their number.

I think the [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) decision should be reconsidered.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Motti about the localization right now. If only four users are effected, well that is not going to help much right now. In the future, where users have thousands of badges and Jon Skeet has millions... This can be easily applied to help. This is too much of an early time to apply this.

The only thing is that this should be [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). This can be apllied but not now. Until we have a lot more users where the badge count exceed the user card, this request can wait.

A way to bypass this is by looking through the user's [expanded usercard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) (if they have one by having at least 1k rep) or just visit their profile instead. So for me, this should be applied later and not now.