# Player profile is not wide enough

Tags: bug, design

I saw this today on programmers.stackexchange:

[image: bug screenshot]

The number representing the bronze medals should actually be 222 but, since the table cell doesn't have enough width, it doesn't fit.

I observed the same behaviour on Firefox v24, IE10 and Chrome v32 (all on Windows 7).

I recommend:

- increasing the width of the table cell or
- don't align it so much to the right or
- (my favourite) don't use a `<table>` for this.

Comment: You forgot *4. Earn less badges*

Comment: The [same request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156205/is-there-enough-space-in-the-user-card-for-users-that-have-a-very-large-number-o) was closed as *too localized* an year ago, citing Jon Skeet nonetheless.

Comment: @brasofilo I think that question was wrongfully closed. Those gold/silver/bronze circles have greater size/width on certain sites within the StackExchange network (among which is Programmers). So, while this issue only appears ocassionaly on SO itself, it becomes more and more present on other sites because more and more people cross that reputation/badges barrier.